# How to draw an element over following items in QML layouts

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm working on a `DatePicker` control for `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` I have problem on drawing popup calendar over other page items. does anyone help me on this ?

Component Screenshot

[image]

My DatePicker source code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as OldControls

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: childrenRect.width
    height: childrenRect.height
    clip: true

    property bool expanded: false
    property bool enabled: true

    property alias selectedDate: cal.selectedDate

    MouseArea {
        height: expanded ? txt.height + cal.height : txt.height
        width: expanded ? Math.max(txt.width, cal.width) : txt.width
        hoverEnabled: true
        enabled: root.enabled
        onHoveredChanged: {
            expanded =  root.enabled && containsMouse
        }

        TextField {
            id: txt
            enabled: root.enabled
            text: cal.selectedDate
            inputMask: "0000-00-00"
        }

        OldControls.Calendar {
            id: cal
            anchors.top: txt.bottom
            anchors.left: txt.left
            visible: expanded
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my `DatePicker` usage in page:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import "./Components"

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    GridLayout {

        columns: 2
        Text { text: qsTr("Date Filter: ") }
        DatePicker {}

        Text { text: qsTr("name filter: ") }
        TextField {}
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? What wrong with the layout? Usually you have to set [z](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop) property to manage layers.

Comment: ... or create the higher layer after the lower.

Comment: as you can see the calendar layer draws under next `TextField`. unfortunately setting `z` property wont fixed the issue. also I need to add items in current order.

Comment: To complete the answer of @folibis, you can simply do `DatePicker { z: 2}`.

Comment: @JulienDéramond thanks, setting `z` property for `DatePicker` fixed my issue.